# JavaScript in a PHP plugin

Tags: plugins, php, javascript

I am writing a plugin (in PHP) that outputs an `array`.

The resulting array should be the input for some JavaScript file that outputs a chart (.png image) based on the array.

With this in mind, I should pass variables to JavaScript from the PHP plugin (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)).

I wonder if the process with a plugin is different from an ordinary PHP file...

The JS chart should be displayed according to user action.

---

In a nutshell:

How can I call the JS file, pass a variable to it via an ordinary plugin?

Comment: Note that PHP doesn't call JS, rather JS either finds the data is already on the page, or JS makes a request to the server to retrieve it. Think of it as mission control and lunar astronauts. The PHP factory builds the space shuttle, and the JS astronauts operate it when it lands. The factory can't rely on objects on the moon being moved by JS astronauts, they're still on earth waiting to be launched. You can send supplies with them but once they're sent they're sent. Once the astronauts are there they have to radio home to request a new supply shuttle

Comment: Thank you for this elucidating analogy! Still, do you know if the methods used to "send supplies" from an ordinary PHP file are still the same for a wp-plugin? Many thanks for considering my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript) you linked to is still valid, the only part that changes is the AJAX part.

Specifically, there are now 2 options:

- Admin AJAX API: A legacy API, most tutorials will use this, but it's much harder to secure, and provides little to no help. If it isn't implemented right you will have no clues as to why it isn't working
- REST API endpoints: These return JSON, and have significantly more support and helping structures. You can define the parameters you expect in a request and it'll tell you if you didn't include them, etc This is much easier and newer

e.g. lets add an endpoint:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
        register_rest_route( 'tomjn/v1', '/test/', array(
                'methods' => 'GET',
                'callback' => 'tomjn_rest_test'
        ) );
} );
```

This says, when a `GET` request is made to `/wp-json/tomjn/v1/test` call the function `tomjn_rest_test` to get the result:

```
function tomjn_rest_test( $request ) {
        return "moomins";
}
```

[image]

Which we can then fetch in javascript, here's a jQuery example:

```
<script>
jQuery.ajax({
    url: <?php echo wp_json_encode( esc_url_raw( rest_url( 'tomjn/v1/test' ) ) ); ?>
}).done(function( data ) {
    jQuery( '#tomsword' ).text( data );
});
</script>
```